# Wifi adapter not showing up in ifconfig and nmcli

Tags: wifi, connection, internet

Neither ifconfig -a nor nmcli dev show display a wifi adapter on my Raspberry Pi4B.

After executing the following commands (which originally were listed in a related post (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1515171):

```
rmmod brcmfmac

rmmod brcmutil

rmmod cfg80211

modprobe brcmfmac
```

both ifconfig -a and nmcli dev show list wlan0 as one of the items.

ifconfig allows me to 'up' the wlan0 interface.

However, when I run nmcli dev wifi rescan to see what networks I can connect to I get a message saying "Error: No Wi-Fi device found."

Also, after a reboot, wlan0 becomes invisible again and I have to execute all those commands again.

The OS is Oracle Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Get another OS, or take your question to the U&L SE - someone there may have some experience with your OS. This is [**Raspberry Pi SE**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions), and your question isn't related to the RPi hardware.

Comment: @Seamus yeah, not helpful. It's a RPi version of Oracle Linux, and the Wifi chip is certainly Raspberry...